# Julia MethodError Array Int64

Tags: julia, julia-jump

I've hit my next roadblock in some code I'm trying to debug and work through.

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching Array(::Type{Int64}, ::Int64)
Closest candidates are:
  Array(::LinearAlgebra.UniformScaling, ::Integer, ::Integer) at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.1\LinearAlgebra\src\uniformscaling.jl:345
```

I looked through material provided and it looks like array definitions may have changed to using `arr` or `Array{Int64,0}` ... but those didn't seem to work for me either. Any advice? Thank you in advance!

```
    # Puts the output of one lineup into a format that will be used later
    if status==:Optimal
        data_lineup_copy = Array(Int64, 0)
        for i=1:num_data
            if getValue(data_lineup[i]) >= 0.9 && getValue(data_lineup[i]) <= 1.1
                data_lineup_copy = vcat(data_lineup_copy, fill(1,1))
            else
                data_lineup_copy = vcat(data_lineup_copy, fill(0,1))
            end
        end
        for i=1:num_shot
            if getValue(shot_lineup[i]) >= 0.9 && getValue(shot_lineup[i]) <= 1.1
                data_lineup_copy = vcat(data_lineup_copy, fill(1,1))
            else
                data_lineup_copy = vcat(data_lineup_copy, fill(0,1))
            end
        end
        return(data_lineup_copy)
    end
end
    data1 = Array(Int64, 0)
    data2 = Array(Int64, 0)
    data3 = Array(Int64, 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

`Array(Int64, 0)` would create an empty `Int64` 1D array (i.e. `Vector`) on older versions (probably pre-0.6 era).

Now, to create an empty `Int64` 1D array, you can use any of

```
data1 = Array{Int64, 1}(undef, 0) # where `1`, the second type parameter is for the dimension
data1 = Array{Int64}(undef, 0)
data1 = Vector{Int64}(undef, 0)
data1 = Vector{Int64}()
data1 = Int64[]
```

You can always consult to the official documentation for different ways of [array construction](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/index.html#Construction-and-Initialization-1) in Julia.

Comment: You have to write `Vector{Int64}(undef, 0)` or `Vector{Int64}()`. Ah - I see it got updated :).

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński Yeah, that was quick :). Added `Vector{Int64}()` so your comment was still useful!